# iCloud streaming

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro, streaming

I have an Apple TV and it works great. I can stream my movies and TV shows from the cloud and watch them on my TV.

I also have a MacBook Air, with a small HD. How can I stream my movies and TV shows from the cloud and watch them on my MacBook Air when I'm out of town? Download to watch isn't a good fit because of limited HD space.

Answer (score 1):

No. iCloud does not have movie streaming for Macs [(yet)](http://www.bgr.com/2011/10/13/apple-close-to-deals-for-icloud-movie-streaming/). Although I would suggest Hulu or Netflix instead, it may be more costly.